# create global variables in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

i have a web application with multiple pages. Each page is calling a class method to fetch data from database. Some of these calls are redundant, meaning we are firing queries multiple times to database to fetch same data. I want to query database once and store the result in some global variable, not sessions, so that pages can access those variables. I have already tried singleton pattern design, but it doesn't accept parameters while object creation. Please help

Comment: Any reasoning on the fact to avoid sessions?

Comment: This seems like a perfect time to use session?

Comment: It's not a use case fir session since he doesn't inficate the state changes per user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Application.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx) to store the result and then access it in multiple pages. But remember that this information will be shared by all the users of your site.

```
DataTable dataTable = GetDataFromDatabase();
HttpContext.Current.Cache["CahcedTable"] = dataTable;
```

To access it:

```
DataTable dataTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["CachedTable"] as DataTable;
if(dataTable != null)
{
     //your code e.g. gridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Comment: also, if you are using SQL Server, it is possible enable (if it's not enabled by default) a query caching on server side, so the result of the query will be cached for some time and on the next *same* query, no IO will be executed, but returned result stored in memory: much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static class, it (along with all it's static properties / fields) will only exist once per applucation domain (so, unless you do a few very specific thibgs, once per website)